# Error when trying to save to database

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I got this Error I dont know where have I done wrong Please Help.Thanks in advance:

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'message' not readable on type org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:335)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:283)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.Error_jsp._jspService(Error_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: A good idea is to provide the code you use when you want to add something to the database

Answer (score 0):

Based on stack trace, you are trying to display error message from exception via EL (Expression Language) on error.jsp, probably like this:

```
${exception.message}
```

As @dunni pointed out, it should work, because GenericJDBCException has method getMessage().

You can try to call method expicitly:

```
${exception.getMessage()}
```

This exception points that message property is not readable.
Are you wrapping GenericJDBCException as inner class into some other class and visibility is not public, like this:

```
 // note that this is a package-private visible class
 class ExceptionWrapper {
     private Throwable exception;

     public Throwable getException() {
         return exception;
     }
 }
```

Or like this:

```
public class ExceptionWrapper {
     private Throwable exception;

     // note that access is package-private method
     Throwable getException() {
         return exception;
     }
 }
```

Since you are using Spring, so you can use its Exception Resolver mechanism to resolve different types of exceptions, as shown here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Every exception has the method getMessage(), it's part of Throwable.